# Replace keyword with a javascript expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string like `hey! <input/>, Welcome` in a template.

I need to replace every `<input/>` with the a JS expression `this.input`.

eg:

```
//Input
"hey! <input/>, Welcome";

Output should be:    
"hey! " + this.input + ", Welcome";
```

I can do a replace on the string with `" + this.input + "` but the problem is what if `<input/>` at the start or the end?

What is the best way to handle this?

Edit:

I don't want the output to be a string. I want the output to be a valid JS expression.

```
Valid inputs:
1) "hey! <input/>, Welcome";
2) "<input/>, Welcome";
3) "Welcome <input/>"

Outputs:
1) "hey! " + this.input + ", Welcome";
2) this.input + ", Welcome";
3) "Welcome " + this.input;
```

Comment: in a text editor?  on a web form?  where is the input coming from?

Comment: @anubhava this is not a duplicate of that question. I have to replace with a javascript expression.

Comment: @mrrogers This is in a template and i need to process such a string to output.

Comment: So like,  `"hey! <input/>, Welcome".replace(/<input\/>/g, '" + this.input + "');` will give you `"hey! " + this.input + ", Welcome"`. Like that?

Comment: @thomas Yes like that. but the problem is what if <input/> is the first word in the string?

Comment: @ChiragJain Please post exactly the expected input and the desired output.

Comment: @anubhava I may need a replace but this is nowhere close to being duplicate because in this i we need to handle where the ``keyword`` is. It's not a global replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comments above you can use:

```
var input = 'foo';
var str = "hey! <input/>, Welcome";
str = str.replace(/(.*?)<input\/>(.*)/, '$1' + this.input + '$2');

console.log(str);
//=> "hey! foo, Welcome"
```

Comment: Took the first valid input in the question and ran your code. Give me this: ``"hey! hey! <input/>, Welcome, Welcome``

Comment: That's not correct testing. I am just getting `hey! undefined, Welcome"` since `this.input` is undefined. Let me put full code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
"hey! <input/>, Welcome".replace(/<input\/>/, this.input);
```

**EDIT:**

John Reisig made a [blog entry](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) about making a minimal templating language parser in javascript. It's well written and may be a good starting point for your own templating language.

Comment: I dont want the output to be a string like "hey this.input, Welcome.".

Comment: It should be a valid JS expression like "hey, " + this.input + ", Welcome"

Comment: Is `input` just a placeholder variable?

Comment: yes. replace the placeholder to create a valid js expression.